# multiple new cordova errors

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

```
file:///android_asset/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND phonegap.js:1183 
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.  phonegap.js:1176 
Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded phonegap.js:1176
```

I recently started getting the above errors.  My best guesses as to why is that it has something to do with the plugins or similar.  I have always included the phonegap.js file but recently I started getting errors that cordova.js was not found.  So I included that and got a different error saying it was already included, so I included it like this: `<script src="../platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js"></script>` which stopped that error but started the `cordova_plugins.js` error instead.

Any help around this would be appreciated.

Comment: try with just <script src="cordova.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks! that solved one part of the problem, hopefully I can work out the other errors with that one gone.